# HttpURLConnection with Youtube gets 429 for every GET request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to get the response code of youtube URLs but it gets 429 for any request and it doesn't return in the header number of seconds to wait between requests (Retry-After)
this code works fine with any URLs except for youtube URLs any help?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                int retry = 0;
                boolean delay = false;
                int MIN_RETRY_AFTER = 2;
                int MAX_RETRY_AFTER = 10;
                int status = 0;
                int retryAfter = 0;
                int random = 0;
                URL u;
                do {
                    if (delay) {
                        Thread.sleep(1000*retryAfter);
                    }
                    String url = "https://youtu.be/WI33lnZCg8w";

                    u = new URL(url);
                    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) u.openConnection();
                    random = (int) Math.random() * 10000;
                    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "skym/1.0.8 /" + random);
                    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    con.setDoOutput(false);
                    con.setDoInput(true);
                    con.setUseCaches(false);
                    con.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                    con.setConnectTimeout(30000);
                    con.setReadTimeout(30000);
                    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
                    status = con.getResponseCode();
    //              to get the time you should wait before the next request
                    retryAfter = con.getHeaderFieldInt("Retry-After", -1);
                    if (retryAfter < 0) {
                        retryAfter = 0;
                    }
                    if (retryAfter < MIN_RETRY_AFTER) {
                        retryAfter = MIN_RETRY_AFTER;
                    } else if (retryAfter > MAX_RETRY_AFTER) {
                        retryAfter = MAX_RETRY_AFTER;
                    }
                    con.disconnect();
                    System.out.println(status);
                    System.out.println(retryAfter);
                    System.out.println("Done in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
                    retry++;
                    delay = true;
                } while (retry < 5 && status == 429);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I tried to run your code and this is what I got: 
(200
2
Done in 3038)
maybe the problem lies elsewhere?

Comment: this problem occurs only on the server not on local